# SQLiteDatabase.query method

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the query method of SQLiteDatabase. How do I use the query method?

I tried this:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(
    tableName, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

**tableColumns** - columns parameter is constructed as follows.

```
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
```

If we need to get all the fields, how should the column parameter to be constructed. Do we need to include all the Field Names in String array?

How do I properly use the query method?

Comment: Try a simple approach like [this](http://pastebin.com/3pfzXMgv)

Comment: I know that method. But I am trying to learn how to implement query method instead of rawQuery.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

**tableColumns**

- `null` for all columns as in `SELECT * FROM ...`
- `new String[] { "column1", "column2", ... }` for specific columns as in `SELECT column1, column2 FROM ...` - you can also put complex expressions here:
  `new String[] { "(SELECT max(column1) FROM table1) AS max" }` would give you a column named `max` holding the max value of `column1`

**whereClause**

- the part you put after `WHERE` without that keyword, e.g. `"column1 > 5"`
- should include `?` for things that are dynamic, e.g. `"column1=?"` -> see `whereArgs`

**whereArgs**

- specify the content that fills each `?` in `whereClause` in the order they appear

**the others**

- just like `whereClause` the statement after the keyword or `null` if you don't use it.

**Example**

```
String[] tableColumns = new String[] {
    "column1",
    "(SELECT max(column1) FROM table2) AS max"
};
String whereClause = "column1 = ? OR column1 = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
    "value1",
    "value2"
};
String orderBy = "column1";
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query("table1", tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs,
        null, null, orderBy);

// since we have a named column we can do
int idx = c.getColumnIndex("max");
```

is equivalent to the following raw query

```
String queryString =
    "SELECT column1, (SELECT max(column1) FROM table1) AS max FROM table1 " +
    "WHERE column1 = ? OR column1 = ? ORDER BY column1";
sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryString, whereArgs);
```

---

By using the Where/Bind -Args version you get automatically escaped values and you don't have to worry if input-data contains `'`.

Unsafe: `String whereClause = "column1='" + value + "'";`
Safe: `String whereClause = "column1=?";`

because if value contains a `'` your statement either breaks and you get exceptions or does unintended things, for example `value = "XYZ'; DROP TABLE table1;--"` might even drop your table since the statement would become two statements and a comment:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where column1='XYZ'; DROP TABLE table1;--'
```

using the args version `XYZ'; DROP TABLE table1;--` would be escaped to `'XYZ''; DROP TABLE table1;--'` and would only be treated as a value. Even if the `'` is not intended to do bad things it is still quite common that people have it in their names or use it in texts, filenames, passwords etc. So always use the args version. (It is okay to build `int` and other primitives directly into `whereClause` though)

Comment: Where does Limit/offset fall into in this... group by? having? orderby?

Comment: @Lion789 there are several versions that have a `limit` parameter, e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 it's all just simple text concatenation in the end so you can put e.g. `"some_column LIMIT 10"` into `orderBy` and it would still work

Comment: Any option here to join 2 tables?

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje you should be able put e.g. `table1 CROSS JOIN table2` as the tablename. But there is a point where I would look at  rawquery: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10598137/995891

Comment: but I am not using rawquery, What should I do in this case

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje whatever you feel more comfortable with / looks cleaner in the end. The `query` methods are merely adding a few keywords like `SELECT` and `FROM` to the arguments [(see source)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java#L201) then do a `rawQuery` with the resulting query string. If your query does not fit well into the available arguments of `query`, just write the query string yourself.

Answer (score 25):

This is a more general answer meant to be a quick reference for future viewers.

**Example**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

String table = "table2";
String[] columns = {"column1", "column3"};
String selection = "column3 =?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"apple"};
String groupBy = null;
String having = null;
String orderBy = "column3 DESC";
String limit = "10";

Cursor cursor = db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```

**Explanation from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))**

> - `table`     String: The table name to compile the query against.
> - `columns`   String: A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data
>     from storage that isn't going to be used.
> - `selection`     String: A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing
>     null will return all rows for the given table.
> - `selectionArgs`     String: You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they
>     appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.
> - `groupBy`   String: A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null
>     will cause the rows to not be grouped.
> - `having`    String: A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor, if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING
>     clause (excluding the HAVING itself). Passing null will cause all row
>     groups to be included, and is required when row grouping is not being
>     used.
> - `orderBy`   String: How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the
>     default sort order, which may be unordered.
> - `limit`     String: Limits the number of rows returned by the query, formatted as LIMIT clause. Passing null denotes no LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 19):

Where clause and args work together to form the WHERE statement of the SQL query. So say you looking to express

```
WHERE Column1 = 'value1' AND Column2 = 'value2'
```

Then your whereClause and whereArgs will be as follows

```
String whereClause = "Column1 =? AND Column2 =?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"value1", "value2"};
```

If you want to select all table columns, i believe a null string passed to tableColumns will suffice.

Comment: don't enclose `?` in `'`, the `'` is added automatically if required

Answer (score 4):

if your SQL query is like this

```
SELECT col-1, col-2 FROM tableName WHERE col-1=apple,col-2=mango
GROUPBY col-3 HAVING Count(col-4) > 5  ORDERBY col-2 DESC LIMIT 15;
```

Then for query() method, we can do as:-

```
String table = "tableName";
String[] columns = {"col-1", "col-2"};
String selection = "col-1 =? AND col-2=?";       
String[] selectionArgs = {"apple","mango"};
String groupBy =col-3;
String having =" COUNT(col-4) > 5";
String orderBy = "col-2 DESC";
String limit = "15";

query(tableName, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.query(
        TABLE_NAME,
        new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO },
        TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
        null, null, null, null, null
);
```

`TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID`, here `=` is the `where` clause. To select all values you will have to give all column names:

```
or you can use a raw query like this 
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM permissions_table WHERE name = 'Comics' ", null);
```

and here is a [good tutorial](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/) for database.