# Error with SQL database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a problem and I've been having quite a problem.  I get the following error:

```
03-26 20:34:27.000: E/SQLiteLog(8930): (1) near "INTEGER": syntax error
03-26 20:34:27.002: E/DatabaseUtils(8930): Writing exception to parcel
03-26 20:34:27.002: E/DatabaseUtils(8930): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near    
"INTEGER": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM story_table WHERE TITLE  
LIKE ?  ORDER BY nullLOGIN_ID INTEGER ,STORY_ID INTEGER ,TITLE TEXT ,BODY TEXT ,AUDIO_LINK 
TEXT ,VIDEO_LINK TEXT ,IMAGE_NAME TEXT ,IMAGE_LINK TEXT ,TAGS TEXT ,CREATION_TIME INTEGER 
,STORY_TIME INTEGER ,LATITUDE REAL ,LONGITUDE REAL
```

Here's what I got for my code.  Could someone please help me out with that part.  I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing there.

```
public Cursor query(final String table, final String[] projection,
        final String selection, final String[] selectionArgs,
        final String sortOrder) {
return db.query(table, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder 
            + Story_LoginId + " INTEGER ," 
            + Story_StoryId + " INTEGER ," 
            + Story_Title + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_Body + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_AudioLink + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_VideoLink + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_ImageName + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_ImageMetaData + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_Tags + " TEXT ," 
            + Story_CreationTime + " INTEGER ," 
            + Story_StoryTime + " INTEGER ," 
            + Story_Latitude + " REAL ," 
            + Story_Longitude + " REAL  ");

}
```

Comment: What do you need, just a select with order by?

Answer (score 2):

Your log show why this get error.

```
SELECT * FROM story_table WHERE TITLE LIKE ?  ORDER BY nullLOGIN_ID INTEGER ,STORY_ID INTEGER ,TITLE TEXT ,BODY TEXT ,AUDIO_LINK TEXT ,VIDEO_LINK TEXT ,IMAGE_NAME TEXT ,IMAGE_LINK TEXT ,TAGS TEXT ,CREATION_TIME INTEGER ,STORY_TIME INTEGER ,LATITUDE REAL ,LONGITUDE REAL
```

Select query not need datatype.
datatype need for create table.
You must change your query string.

```
SELECT * FROM story_table WHERE TITLE LIKE ? ORDER BY nullLOGIN_ID, STORY_ID ...
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the logCat you have a problem here "`ORDER BY nullLOGIN_ID INTEGER`", `Select` clause don´t need data types.

if you only need a select from a table, this is an example:

```
return db.query(table, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
```

More info: 
**[SQLiteDatabase.query method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600670/sqlitedatabase-query-method)**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `cast` Columns like `Story_LoginId, Story_StoryId, Story_CreationTime` into `Text` first before concatenation them to literal values like **INTEGER or REAL**.