# Android database - attempt to re-open an already-closed object?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Also it never happened on any of my devices, I am receiving quite a lot crash reports from customers like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object
```

Crashes always happens on **db.query** line (7th line of code):

```
        ArrayList<AlarmItem> items = new ArrayList<AlarmItem>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            db = instance.getReadableDatabase();
            // CRASH next line:       
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_ALARMS, null, null, null, null, null, null); 
            ...
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            ...
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();

            if (db != null)
                db.close();
        }

        return items;
```

Anybody know what can be the reason? Thanks!

EDIT:

All methods are synchronized, so there can't be more than 1 operation in a moment.
Instance is a singleton, so it shouldn't be problem.

Comment: Are you protecting against things like calls to finish() that might be occurring in parallel?  Also is 'instance' initialized in onCreate or at the class level?  It sounds like a race condition related to the unexpected threading from your development environment.  E.g., a multi-core device.

Comment: change instance.getReadableDatabase() to  instance.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: @caskey all methods are synchronized, so there can't be more than 1 operation in a moment. Instance is singleton, so it shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: @NaveedAli He shouldn't need a writable db to query.

Comment: @Naveed - why? I just need to read database, not write to it

Comment: @qkx Synchronization doesn't protect against everything.  It prevents two methods from being run at once, but it doesn't prevent a method from being run after the database helper has been closed or after the db has been closed if the database object is cached anywhere.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be happen if you are attempting to assign result to `Cursor`, which was already closed. Have you tried to determine wheter it was closed?

```
if  (!cursor.isClosed()){
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: question updated with full method code, it should be impossible for cursor object to be already closed...check code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try this:

```
if (db == null || !db.isOpen())
    db = getReadableDatabase();
```

to make sure you dont open it twice

Comment: question updated with full method code, it should be impossible for db object to be already opened, check code

Answer (score 0):

You should select something like

```
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.query("table1", tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs,
null, null, orderBy);
```

Also, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10601764