# How to know which data is from which table when you select data from multiple tables?

Tags: java, sql

I have a table of client contain the client id, name and last name, job ..etc...
also I have 16 tables of the grants of client each table contain a different data(different grant) relate with the client by a foreign key of "id".......
for example this is costumer table"clients":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4IkK.png)

and this is an example for an grant of client called order:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqaL9.png)

So when I search for client, I search also for all the grants that he benefited them, and maybe a client can benefit from the same grant more than once........that's means we can find more than one row in the same table relate with the same client:

As you see in the table Of order we have two row relate with the client who have id=2.: So I want to make one query to select all data from the first table and the second of the client `"Where id =2"`

the problem is how I can get all the information relate with that client and to which row from which table ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access data from particular Table you can see the following code It may help you

```
    public Cursor getInformation(databaseOperations dbo){

    SQLiteDatabase Db = dbo.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.CONTACT_NO, TableData.TableInfo.EMAIL_ID,TableData.TableInfo.PROFILE_PATH};
    Cursor CR =Db.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    return CR;
}
```

If you need data from particular row or column then you can pass different argument instead of null in  DB.query.
To know about different parameters you can see just this answer [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600670/sqlitedatabase-query-method)

I hope it will help you. To know more about parameter details of db.query() function you can go through google search.

Comment: I guess my question it's not clear !!

what I want is:
 to select all the information of a client in many tables so I search for it by his id which is a foreign key in these tables ... the problem is how to know which data is from which table in Resultset..how I get it from resultset ??