# SQLite Listview onclick filters db to open result in new activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-sqlite

I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39262908/6781422) but with no answer im trying to restructure or use a different approach.

I've got a DB that is opened and copied from the assets folder, this works correctly because the first activity opens and displays correctly from it..

The idea is that when you open the app and call the class to open the bible, it opens the book class and has a ListView, in the listview is all the bible books, when clicked, it should open the chapter activity and in its ListView display all the book's chapters, when selecting a chapter it should open the verse Activity and in its ListView display all the verses.

So far, the book Activity displays the book names, but when I click on it, it only displays a white screen...
Nothing shows errors in the logcat.

I've tried using the Intent but I cant get it to work, Can someone please assist me with this?

Maybe I'm using the intent wrong? 
Here is the code I think you guys need to see if there's a problem somewhere
Excuse the Afrikaans terms I use for naming

**From my main activity I use:**

```
public class BybelActivityBoek extends Activity {

private ListView listviewBybel;
private customAdapterBoektext adapter_customAdapterBoektext;
private List<defineBybeldbBoek> defineBybeldbBoekList;
private DBHandlerBoek DBHandlerBoek_DBHelperBoek;
public String boek_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView (R.layout.activity_bybel_boek);
    listviewBybel = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BybelBoekListView);
    DBHandlerBoek_DBHelperBoek = new DBHandlerBoek(this);

    //Check exists database
    File Database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DBHandlerBoek.DBNAME);
    if(false == Database.exists()){
        DBHandlerBoek_DBHelperBoek.getReadableDatabase();

        //Copy DB
        if (DBHandlerBoek.copyDatabase(this)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Databasis Suksesvol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Databasis Probleem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
    }

    //Get bybel list in db when db exists
    defineBybeldbBoekList = DBHandlerBoek_DBHelperBoek.getListBybel();

    //Init adapter
    adapter_customAdapterBoektext = new customAdapterBoektext(this, defineBybeldbBoekList);

    //Set adapter for listview
    listviewBybel.setAdapter(adapter_customAdapterBoektext);

    //Listview item click listener
    //BybelActivityHoofstuk will be launched by passing boek_id
    listviewBybel.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){

            //on selecting a book
            //BybelHoofstukActivity will be launched to show hoofstukke inside
            Intent boekIntent = new Intent(BybelActivityBoek.this, BybelActivityHoofstuk.class);
            boekIntent.putExtra(boek_id, String.valueOf(arg3));
            startActivity(boekIntent);
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

**And then sub activity:**

```
public class BybelActivityHoofstuk extends Activity {
private ListView listviewHoofstuk;
private customAdapterHoofstuktext adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext;
private List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> defineBybeldbHoofstukList;
private DBHandlerHoofstuk DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> HoofstukList;

//Boek id
String boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bybel_hoofstuk);

    listviewHoofstuk = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BybelHoofstukListView);
    DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper = new DBHandlerHoofstuk(this);

    //Check exists database
    File Database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DBHandlerBoek.DBNAME);
    if(false == Database.exists()){
    DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    //Get boek id
    Intent boekIntent = getIntent();
    boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek = boekIntent.getStringExtra("boek_id");

    //hashmap for listview
    HoofstukList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //Set adapter for listview
    listviewHoofstuk.setAdapter(adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext);

    //Get bybel list in db when db exists
    defineBybeldbHoofstukList = DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper.getListHoofstuk();

    //Init adapter
    adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext = new customAdapterHoofstuktext(this,defineBybeldbHoofstukList);

        listviewHoofstuk.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){
            //on selecting single track get vers text
            Intent hoofstukid = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BybelActivityVers.class);
            //to get vers hoofstuk_id is needed
           String hoofstuk_id = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();

            hoofstukid.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id);

            startActivity(hoofstukid);
        }
    });
}
 }
}
```

**My main DBClass:**

```
public class defineBybeldbBoek extends AppCompatActivity{

public int _id;
private String _hebreeus;
private String _afrikaans;

public defineBybeldbBoek(int boek_id, String _hebreeus, String _afrikaans){
    this._id = boek_id;
    this._hebreeus = _hebreeus;
    this._afrikaans = _afrikaans;

}

public int getboek_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_hebreeus() {
    return _hebreeus;
}

public String get_afrikaans() {
    return _afrikaans;
}

}
```

**My sub DBClass:**

```
public class defineBybeldbHoofstuk extends AppCompatActivity{

private int hoofstuk_se_boek_id;
private int _id;
private int _hoofstuk;

public defineBybeldbHoofstuk(int hoofstuk_se_boek_id, int hoofstuk_id, int _hoofstuk){
    this.hoofstuk_se_boek_id = hoofstuk_se_boek_id;
    this._id = hoofstuk_id;
    this._hoofstuk = _hoofstuk;
}

public int get_hoofstuk() {
    return _hoofstuk;
}

public int hoofstuk_se_boek_id() {
    return hoofstuk_se_boek_id;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

}
```

**The main DBHandler:**

```
public class DBHandlerBoek extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DBNAME = "db name.db";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "correct db path here";

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public static final String TABLE_BOEK = "table_boek";
public static final String COLUMN_BOEK_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_BOEK_HEBREEUS = "_hebreeus";
public static final String COLUMN_BOEK_AFRIKAANS = "_afrikaans";

public static final String TABLE_HOOFSTUK = "table_hoofstuk";
public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_SE_BOEK_ID = "_id";

public DBHandlerBoek(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

//Blank want db bestaan klaar
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
//When app gets installed, copy db to device when this activity runs
public static boolean copyDatabase(Context context){
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DBHandlerBoek.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DBHandlerBoek.DBLOCATION + DBHandlerBoek.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("BybelActivityBoek", "DB Copied");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

//blank want db word ekstern geupgrade
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//maak db oop
public void opendatabase(){
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (mDatabase !=null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }

    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

//maak db toe
public void closeDatabase(){
    if (mDatabase!=null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<defineBybeldbBoek> getListBybel(){
    defineBybeldbBoek defineBybeldbBoek = null;
    List<defineBybeldbBoek> defineBybelDBList = new ArrayList<>();
    opendatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_boek", null);/*(die tabel se naam)*/
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        defineBybeldbBoek = new defineBybeldbBoek(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
        defineBybelDBList.add(defineBybeldbBoek);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return defineBybelDBList;
}
}
```

**The sub DBHandler:**

```
public class DBHandlerHoofstuk extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DBNAME = "db name.db";
public static final String DBLOCATION = "correct db path here";

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

public static final String TABLE_HOOFSTUK = "table_hoofstuk";
public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_BOEK_ID = "hoofstuk_se_boek_id";
public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_HOOFSTUK = "_hoofstuk";

public DBHandlerHoofstuk(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.mContext = context;
}

//Blank want db bestaan klaar
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

//blank want db word ekstern geupgrade
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//maak db oop
public void opendatabase(){
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (mDatabase !=null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }

    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

//maak db toe
public void closeDatabase(){
    if (mDatabase!=null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> getListHoofstuk(){
    defineBybeldbHoofstuk defineBybeldbHoofstuk = null;
    List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> defineBybeldbHoofstukList = new ArrayList<>();
    opendatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_hoofstuk", null);/*(die tabel se naam)*/
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        defineBybeldbHoofstuk = new defineBybeldbHoofstuk(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1),cursor.getInt(2));
        defineBybeldbHoofstukList.add(defineBybeldbHoofstuk);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return defineBybeldbHoofstukList;
}
}
```

Comment: First important thing is you should not use different classes for database operation, all kind of operations related to tables and database should be in one single file for any number of tables, second you are passing wrong value you need to pass it like defineBybeldbBoekList.get(arg2).getBookId;, and third main thing is when you are taking this id in second sub class where are you using it ? you never use it for getting particular data so this need so many changes and modification

Comment: "But with no answer" - You did get 2 answers, actually. And you really should provide a **[mcve]** instead of having us sort though all this code to answer what you really want

Comment: Also, not all classes need to extend something. For example, `defineBybeldbBoek` nor `defineBybeldbHoofstuk` are an Activity. They are plain Java objects

Comment: @Vickyexpert this is why I asked the question, because I dont know what to do, Ive gotten bits and pieces of code from tutorials, I cant find any tutorial that shows what I want to do... So I came here for help

Comment: @cricket_007 I dont know how I could have displayed this code shorter, im trying to show how the code looks and then someone could tell me where the problem is since I dont get any errors and only a white screen

Comment: Alright, then describe what you have tried to solve the problem. Since the ListView is empty, then you are not getting data into a list or an adapter. Or the XML layout is hiding the ListView. Or the database is not being copied correctly. It should be possible for you to place `Log` statements in many places of your code, or set breakpoints in the IDE in order to debug the problem.

Comment: Also, `boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek` is not being used anywhere in your question - You only assigned the variable from the Intent. From my previous answer to your other question, you likely are needing to query the database using that value. You know how to write a `SELECT * FROM table` statement. So, you need to figure out how to add a `WHERE` condition to that in order to filter for a particular value

Comment: @FDupie Check My Answer Below and make required changes in your app, hope it will run your app and show you data properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned you need to do many modifications in code, but currently You can make your code running by below changes :

**First Change Your getListHoofstuk method as below in DBHandlerHoofstuk class**

```
public List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> getListHoofstuk(String boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek)
{

   defineBybeldbHoofstuk defineBybeldbHoofstuk = null;
   List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> defineBybeldbHoofstukList = new ArrayList<>();
   opendatabase();
   Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_hoofstuk WHERE " + COLUMN_HOOFSTUK_BOEK_ID + " = '" + boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek + "'", null);/*(die tabel se naam)*/

   cursor.moveToFirst();

   while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
       defineBybeldbHoofstuk = new defineBybeldbHoofstuk(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1),cursor.getInt(2));
       defineBybeldbHoofstukList.add(defineBybeldbHoofstuk);
       cursor.moveToNext();
   }

   cursor.close();
   closeDatabase();
   return defineBybeldbHoofstukList;
}
```

**Now Change Your BybelActivityHoofstuk Activity By Below**

```
public class BybelActivityHoofstuk extends Activity
{
    private ListView listviewHoofstuk;
    private customAdapterHoofstuktext adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext;
    private List<defineBybeldbHoofstuk> defineBybeldbHoofstukList;
    private DBHandlerHoofstuk DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> HoofstukList;

    //Boek id
    String boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bybel_hoofstuk);

            listviewHoofstuk = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.BybelHoofstukListView);
            DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper = new DBHandlerHoofstuk(this);


            //Check exists database
            File Database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DBHandlerBoek.DBNAME);
        if(false == Database.exists()){
                DBHandlerBoek_DBHelperBoek.getReadableDatabase();

                //Copy DB
                if (DBHandlerBoek.copyDatabase(this)){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Databasis Suksesvol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Databasis Probleem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                }
            }
            DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            //Get boek id
            Intent boekIntent = getIntent();
            boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek = boekIntent.getStringExtra("boek_id");

            //hashmap for listview
            HoofstukList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //Get bybel list in db when db exists
            defineBybeldbHoofstukList = DBHandlerHoofstuk_DBHelper.getListHoofstuk(boek_id_vanaf_BybelActivityBoek);

        //Init adapter
        adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext = new customAdapterHoofstuktext(this,defineBybeldbHoofstukList);

        //Set adapter for listview
            listviewHoofstuk.setAdapter(adapter_customAdapterHoofstuktext);


        listviewHoofstuk.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3){
                    //on selecting single track get vers text
                    Intent hoofstukid = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BybelActivityVers.class);
                    //to get vers hoofstuk_id is needed
                String hoofstuk_id = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hoofstuk_id)).getText().toString();

                    hoofstukid.putExtra("hoofstuk_id", hoofstuk_id);

                    startActivity(hoofstukid);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! There's a few places I changed the names to the correct ones but it works. I had my ordering of the code wrong and also had one } missing. I changed everything and its now functioning. Thank you!!

Comment: Enjoy Your Coding...