# save All Latitudes and Longitudes in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to save All Latitudes and Longitudes in `Sqlite` Database in `IN_RIDE_LatLng` Table with `latitude` and `longitude` columns names.

Creating Table.

```
   database.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + IN_RIDE_LatLng + " ("
            + Latitude + " TEXT, "
            + Longitude + " TEXT" + ");");
```

Save All Latitude and Longitude

```
public void insertLatLng(Double latitude, Double logitude) {
    try {

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude, latitude);
        contentValues.put(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Longitude, logitude);
        database.insert(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_LatLng, null, contentValues);

        }
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

}}
```

**How can I retrieve all LatLngs in `ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList();`** from Database. 
How Function returns All LatLng List that store in database.

I do this for retrieving list but not working.

```
      public ArrayList<LatLng> getLatLngList() {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT latitude , longitude FROM in_ride_lat_lng" , null);/*(die tabel se naam)*/

       // String[] columns = new String[]{NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude,NewDatabaseForInRideData.Longitude};
        //Cursor cursor = database.query(NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_LatLng, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                latLngList.add(new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude)), cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Longitude))));
               // return latLngList;
            } while (cursor.moveToFirst());

        }
        return latLngList;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return latLngList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look into this https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @pskink i have 100000 more

Comment: i donot need to draw polyLines through these latLngs
i only get and upload this list to server

Comment: What is your actual problem? Data stored in database or not? And data stored but not able to get in list?

Comment: @Vickyexpert yes it store all latLngs but not retrieve as latLng List.

Comment: @AhmadTahir, then try to change your getLatLngList method using my this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320799/sqlite-listview-onclick-filters-db-to-open-result-in-new-activity/39361223#39361223

Comment: @Vickyexpert answer this question

Comment: @pskink i want seprate list of one by one latlng its easy for manage me i use your mathod but i want list from database that store in it

Comment: @pskink its simple i say
that i want all LatLng that store in Database in LatLng ArrayList,  Function Implemented but may be minnor changes required

Comment: i donot want to use ecode method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your `getLatLngList()` method as below:

```
public ArrayList<LatLng> getLatLngList()
{

  ArrayList<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
  Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + NewDatabaseForInRideData.IN_RIDE_LatLng, null);

  cursor.moveToFirst();

  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
      latLngList.add(new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude)),cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(NewDatabaseForInRideData.Latitude))));
      cursor.moveToNext();
  }

  cursor.close();
  return latLngList;
}
```