# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException during my query [SQLite]

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to search my database for a row where `KEY_TOR == place.getTor()`

Here I call the method:

```
DB_Place tor = db_tore.getDBPlace(place.getTor());
```

This is the method:

```
public DB_Place getDBPlace(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DB_TORE_Eintrag, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_PLACE_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_TOR }, KEY_TOR + "=?",
            new String[]{name}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    DB_Place place = new DB_Place(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));

    return place;
}
```

Looks good to me, except that I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.x.x/com.example.ahok.x.UI_MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

What am I missing here? Is it possible that it has something to do with a few of the columns being `null`?

Comment: Try merging these 2 lines `if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();` into one `if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())`

Comment: By the way, which is the sense of retrieving `KEY_TOR`, if you already know that its value is `name`?

Comment: @Rotwang did it. still the same error.

Comment: Moreover, this `new String[]{name}, null, null, null, null);` should be `new String[]{name});`

Comment: @Rotwang To be honest, this is new for me. I copied this from another of my querys that work. In those querys I am looking for the id in the where clause. Do you have any suggestion on how to change the method?

Comment: I gave you my suggestions in the above comments.

Comment: When I change it to `new String[]{name});` it cannot resolve the method anymore.

Comment: Looks like you have to data in your database.

Comment: In the string array there must be **exactly** one item for each placeholder (those funny `?`s, you know).

Comment: is your `KEY_PLACE_ID` is string type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601764/2649012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have any data inserted in your database. Moreover, you've some logical error in your code.

I would like to edit your function like this.

```
public DB_Place getDBPlace(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DB_TORE_Eintrag, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_PLACE_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_TOR }, KEY_TOR + "=?",
                    new String[]{name}, null, null, null, null);

    DB_Place place = null;

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        place = new DB_Place(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    }

    return place;
}
```

**Update**

So if you think its an error of your query, then run simple query like this.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from " + TABLE_DB_TORE_Eintrag + " where " + KEY_TOR + " = '" + name + "'", null);
```

Comment: I took your code and at least the app does not crash anymore. The method does indeed return that `place` is null, even though the database is not empty. I checked it with a method the returns the whole database.

Comment: Print all the rows you have in your `TABLE_DB_TORE_Eintrag` and post it here.

Comment: I think that maybe the where clause doesnt work, but I dont get why. `name` is "Tor 1" and as I checked in the database exists an entry where `KEY_TOR` is "Tor 1"

Comment: Please see the update and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure how to print them, but this is the return array of a method that gets all the data in that database: [Image of the Debugger](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-32105081/debugger.png.html)

Comment: Please try the updated query. I'm taking a look at the debugger.

Comment: This exceptions happens with the new query: "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "1": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from orte where tor = Tor 1"

Comment: The image of the debugger does not load for me. [Reupload](https://i.imgsafe.org/75fc8ccb27.png)

Comment: @Glave You need to quote the name: `select * from orte where tor = 'Tor 1'`

Comment: Yes, i realized that a minute ago, too. I am such an idiot. This happens when you are coding for too long in one sitting. Thank you for getting me there!

Comment: That's why we prefer using the parametrized queries. The string quoting is automatic. And you're less prone to SQL injection.