# Get addresses from Inbox SMS Messages

Tags: java, android, sms, android-cursor, inbox

I want to get addresses from Inbox SMS Messages
I am not sure if my query is correct.

```
        final String SMS_URI_INBOX = "content://sms/inbox";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='?'", null, "address ASC");

        List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                //How to get address
                 spinnerArray.add(address);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like

```
//How to get address      
spinnerArray.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
// OR position of address column into projection is at 2 so you can pass
// direct.         
spinnerArray.add(cur.getString(1));
```

---

Read more about [How to get column value from sqlite cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412040/how-to-get-column-value-from-sqlite-cursor).